# How get the label of the currently inserted tape?

Tags: linux, tape, bacula

I would like to design a debug script that outputs the Bacula's label of the tape currently inserted in the tape loaders and to send the result into Opsview if required.  should those be mounted or not.

(?) How can i get the label of the currently inserted tape in Bacula/Linux?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Bacula : use in `bconsole` the command `mount`.

Linux : Do not know.